# What are some important pros and contras considering using Trilinos?

Tags: trilinos

I'm currently developing a large simulation that will run on many nodes, and, as far as possible, on GPUs. I'm now considering to build it using libraries from the Trilinos project. I would for sure need Kokkos, Tpetra and some linear solver libraries. I also need to deal with a mesh and with construction of FEM equations.

So far, I have the following pros and cons:

**Pro:**

- I get a large number of libraries.
- My solution will be somewhat standardized and therefore more interoperable with other libraries, software, developers, ...
- There's an user community, however, of course, much smaller than for many other programming topics.

**Contra:**

- Installation is tedious. I'm now on day 6...
- According to the hands on tutorial, Tpetra seems to be not very well established yet.
- Compiling for CUDA also seems to be tricky and not very mature.
- The risk that Trilinos does not support something I need. It would probably be very difficult to understand and extend it by myself. Particularly GPU-stuff.
- Same risk for bugs.

I'm looking for some more arguments pro and contra Trilinos, or some advices considering when you would use it and when not. I know that it might be a bit opinion based, but I would be very glad if I you could share some experience and knowledge with me.

Comment: What are the alternatives you are looking at?

Comment: Writing a lot from scratch and use whatever library is needed for a particular task. Going on the same way as I did it for a small scale implementation.

Comment: You might also consider [PETSc](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) if you find the installation for Trilinos to be an annoyance. It has a lot of common functionality with Trilinos, and can [use GPUs](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/features/gpus.html) if that's your fancy. I've had pretty good experiences with it in the past but there's definitely a learning curve.